# Is MKReverseGeocoder delegate method working on separate thread?

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, mkmapview, mkreversegeocoder

I am trying draw route between two location.For that i have two instance of `CLLocation` startPoin,endPoind. I want to convert this two location two corresponding Location Address.After that i want to fetch all route points from Google map webservice. So did the following code.

```
- (void)viewDidLoad{
    [super viewDidLoad];
    locations =[[NSMutableArray alloc]initWithCapacity:2];//For location Name 
    [self.mapView_MP setMapType:MKMapTypeStandard];
    [self.mapView_MP setZoomEnabled:YES];
    [self.mapView_MP setScrollEnabled:YES];
    [self update:startPoint];  //MKReverseGeocoder start point  
    [self update:endPoint];    //MKReverseGeocoder end point

    [self updateRoute];

}

- (void)update:(CLLocation*)loc{
    MKReverseGeocoder *geoCoder = [[MKReverseGeocoder alloc] initWithCoordinate:loc.coordinate];


    geoCoder.delegate = self;
    [geoCoder start];

}
- (void)reverseGeocoder:(MKReverseGeocoder *)geocoder didFindPlacemark:(MKPlacemark *)placemark
{

    NSMutableDictionary *cplace=[[NSMutableDictionary alloc]initWithDictionary:[placemark addressDictionary]];

   // NSLog(@"The geocoder has returned: %@", [cplace objectForKey:@"FormattedAddressLines"] );
   // NSLog(@"The geocoder has returned: %@", [cplace objectForKey:@"Street"] );
    [locations addObject:[cplace objectForKey:@"SubAdministrativeArea"]];
     NSLog(@"The geocoder has returned: %@", locations );
}
- (void)reverseGeocoder:(MKReverseGeocoder *)geocoder didFailWithError:(NSError *)error
{
    NSLog(@"reverseGeocoder:%@ didFailWithError:%@", geocoder, error);
}

- (void)updateRoute {

    self.responseData=[NSMutableData data];  
    NSLog(@" string Formate.................................===%@",locations);   

    NSURLRequest *request=[NSURLRequest requestWithURL:[NSURL URLWithString:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"http://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/directions/json?origin=%@&destination=%@&mode=driving&sensor=false", [locations objectAtIndex:0],[locations objectAtIndex:1]]]];
    [[NSURLConnection alloc] initWithRequest:request delegate:self];    
}
```

In  viewDidLoad i am calling the methods in the order

```
[self update:startPoint];      //MKReverseGeocoder start point  
    [self update:endPoint];    //MKReverseGeocoder end point           
    [self updateRoute];
```

but unfortunately [self updateRoute]; is executing first compare to `MKReverseGeocoder` delegate method. there for the location array is null in side this method. Getting EXEBADACCESS. how can i over come this value.
Inside `MKReverseGeocoder` delegate method i got location name. the Delegate methods is executing any other thread.

Comment: MKReverseGeoCoder is deprecated in iOS 5.0. Use CLGeoCoder.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`MKReverseGeocoder` is deprecated in iOS 5, so you should probably use `CLGeocoder` instead.

That aside, yes, the `start` method is *asynchronous*, as indicated in the documentation. That doesn't necessarily mean that you'll get the results on a different thread, but it means that the method will usually return before results are available.

You need to keep track of your geocoders to call your `updateRoute` method when both have finished.

Comment: NSLog() inside the updateRoute Came First; Currenty i am working in ios 4

Answer (score 1):

It doesn't really matter whether it's executing on another thread. What matters is that you can't control when you get a response.

You should have some logic to say "When I get a value for both the start and end route, call my `updateRoute` method". You could check that the value of the `startPoint` variable is set when you get the value of `endPoint` (and vice versa) and only then call the `updateRoute` function.

Comment: Uing startPoint and endPoint i ReverseGecoder the locationName, and strored in NSMutableArray(locations),this location value is null inside the updateRoute method

Answer (score 0):

if you still wish to use this despite this being deprecated.... you should call your     `[self updateRoute];` in  `- (void)reverseGeocoder:(MKReverseGeocoder *)geocoder didFindPlacemark:(MKPlacemark *)placemark` only if `[locations count]` is 2.

This way the NSURLConnection will be called when you have both the values.

Comment: because NSURLConnection is called even before you have the values from  MKReverseGeocoder..

Comment: please see the second answer.